# different name series in highchart

Tags: codeigniter, highcharts

I want to ask about the name series in highchart. I've made it but series name so one.
so here my code:

```js
 series: [{
            name: <?php echo json_encode($project);?>,
            data: <?php echo json_encode($value);?>,
            shadow : true,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                // color: ['#045396','#ff0000','#00ff00','#0000ff'],
                align: 'center',
                formatter: function() {
                     return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
                }, // one decimal
                y: 0, // 10 pixels down from the top
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        }]
    }
```

and the result:
[image: chart 1]

but i want like this:
[image: chart 2]

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to break apart your series into an array of data objects.

Then when you are instantiating the highcharts object can pass in an xAxis option with the names for these columns:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: [
        'Samsung',
        'Nokia',
        'Blackberry',
        'Apple'
    ]
},
```

Here is a pretty good example which might help you. http://jsfiddle.net/TU7TL/1/

Comment: in category i have been insert with xAxis: {
            categories:  <?php echo json_encode($project);?>
        },

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display four `legend items` instead of one, you need to split your series into four series.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/2wm4jn2q/